# Multiply float by a number using bitwise operators

Tags: c, floating-point, bitwise-operators

I have this function that takes in the bits of a `float` (`f`) as a `uint32_t`. It should use bit operations and + to calculate `f * 2048` and should return the bits of this value as a `uint32_t`.

If the result is too large to be represented as a `float`, `+inf` or `-inf` should be returned returned; and if `f` is `+0`, `-0`, `+inf` or `-inf`, or `Nan`, it should be returned unchanged.

```
uint32_t float_2048(uint32_t f) {
    uint32_t a = (f << 1) ;

    int result = a << 10;

    return result;
}
```

This is what I have so far but if I give it the value '1' it returns 0 instead of 2048. How do I fix this?

Some example inputs and outputs:

```
./float_2048 1
2048
./float_2048 3.14159265
6433.98193
./float_2048 -2.718281828e-20
-5.56704133e-17
./float_2048 1e38
inf
```

Comment: I suggest to start by having a look at the bit patterns of `f` and `f*2048.0f` for some reasonable sized `f`. Only a few bits should change.

Comment: To multiply a floating point number by 2048, wouldn't you want to keep the mantissa the same while increasing the exponent by 11 (since 2^11=2048)? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32

Comment: How would I go about increasing just the exponent?

Comment: Have a look at the bit representation (see the Wikipedia link): based on that, think about what operations you can do that leave the mantissa the same, while changing the exponent in the way that you want.

Comment: @slothrop "wouldn't you want to keep the mantissa the same while increasing the exponent by 11" --> When the |value| < `FLT_MIN`, other actions are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to multiply a floating-point number by a power of 2 (assuming, as is likely, that it is represented in [IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)), we can just add that power to the (binary) exponent part of the representation.

For a single-precision (32-bit) `float` value, that exponent is stored in bits 30-23 and the following code shows how to extract those, add the required value (11, because 2048 = 2<sup>11</sup>), then replace the exponent bits with that modified value.

```c
uint32_t fmul2048(uint32_t f)
{
    #define EXPONENT 0x7F800000u
    #define SIGN_BIT 0x80000000u
    uint32_t expon = (f & EXPONENT) >> 23; // Get exponent value
    f &= ~EXPONENT;  // Remove old exponent
    expon += 11;     // Adding 11 to exponent multiplies by 2^11 (= 2048);
    if (expon > 254) return EXPONENT | (f & SIGN_BIT); // Too big: return +/- Inf
    f |= (expon << 23); // Insert modified exponent
    return f;
}
```

There will, no-doubt, be some "bit trickery" that can be applied to make the code smaller and/or more efficient; but I have avoided doing so in order to keep the code clear. I have also included one error check (for a too large exponent) and the code returns the standard representation for +/- Infinity (all exponent bits set to 1, and keeping the original sign) if that test fails. (I leave other error-checking as an "exercise for the reader".)

Comment: "I leave other error-checking ... " --> Fails for sub-normals, +/-0.0 and NANs.  Also fails when endian, size of `float` differs from `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

To handle all `float` takes more code.

Do some tests so code can assume the expected `float` size, matching endian and (IEEE) encoding.  C does *not* require `float` as 32-bit, matching endian to an integer, not [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) encoding, even though that is common.

Extract the biased exponent and look for its min and max value.

Max values signify NAN or infinity.

Min values are sub-normals and zero and need special handling.  The significand needs to be shifted.  If that result is now a *normal* `float`, re-encode it.

Biased exponents in between simple need an increment and test for exceeding `FLT_MAX`'s exponent.

Tested successfully for all `float`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(float), "Unexpected float size");

#define IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO     0x7F800000u
#define IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO_LSB 0x00800000u
#define IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND     0x007FFFFFu
#define IEEE_SIGNIFICAND_MAX      0x00FFFFFFu
#define IEEE_INFINITY             0x7F800000u

// Scale value by 2048
uint32_t float_2048(uint32_t f) {
  uint32_t expo = f & IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO;
  // Test for infinity or NAN
  if (expo == IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO) {
    return f;
  }
  // Sub-normal and zero test
  if (expo == 0) {
    uint64_t sig = f & IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND;
    sig <<= 11; // *= 2048;
    // If value now a normal one
    if (sig > IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND) {
      expo += IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO_LSB;
      while (sig > IEEE_SIGNIFICAND_MAX) {
        sig >>= 1;
        expo += IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO_LSB;
      }
      f = (f & ~IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO) | (expo & IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO);
    }
    f = (f & ~IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND) | (sig & IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND);
  } else {
    expo += 11 * IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO_LSB; // *= 2048;
    if (expo >= IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO) {
      f &= ~(IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO | IEEE_MASK_SIGNIFICAND);
      f |= IEEE_INFINITY;
    } else {
      f = (f & ~IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO) | (expo & IEEE_MASK_BIASED_EXPO);
    }
  }
  return f;
}
```

Test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union {
  uint32_t u32;
  float f;
} fu32;

int main(void ) {
  // Lightweight test to see if endian matches and IEEE encoding
  assert((fu32) {.u32 = 0x87654321}.f == -1.72477726182e-34f);
  float f[] = {0, FLT_TRUE_MIN, FLT_MIN, 1, FLT_MAX};
  size_t n = sizeof f/sizeof f[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    fu32 x = { .f = f[i] };
    float y0 = x.f * 2048.0f;
    fu32 y1 = { .u32 = float_2048(x.u32) };
    if (memcmp(&y0, &y1.f, sizeof y0)) {
      printf("%.9g %.9g\n", y0, y1.f);
    }
  }
  fu32 x = { .u32 = 0 };
  do {
    fu32 y0 = { .f = isnan(x.f) ? x.f : x.f * 2048.0f };
    fu32 y1 = { .u32 = float_2048(x.u32) };
    if (memcmp(&y0.f, &y1.f, sizeof y0)) {
      printf("%.9g %.9g\n", y0.f, y1.f);
      printf("%08lx %08lx %08lx\n", (unsigned long) x.u32,
          (unsigned long) y0.u32, (unsigned long) y1.u32);
      break;
    }
    x.u32++;
  } while (x.u32 != 0);
  puts("Done");
}
```